# How to create a texture from a bitmap file?

Tags: c++, direct3d12

Can you please help me in finding the equivalent DX12 API/sample code by which I could load a bitmap and create a texture ?

For DX11 it is `D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile` and for DX9 it is `D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx`

Comment: I think this may help you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn899215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494559/creating-a-texture-from-a-image-in-dx-12-vc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following functions from [DirectXTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12), as well as many other.

```
// Standard version
HRESULT __cdecl LoadWICTextureFromMemory(
    _In_ ID3D12Device* d3dDevice,
    _In_reads_bytes_(wicDataSize) const uint8_t* wicData,
    size_t wicDataSize,
    _Outptr_ ID3D12Resource** texture,
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>& decodedData,
    D3D12_SUBRESOURCE_DATA& subresource,
    size_t maxsize = 0);

HRESULT __cdecl LoadWICTextureFromFile(
    _In_ ID3D12Device* d3dDevice,
    _In_z_ const wchar_t* szFileName,
    _Outptr_ ID3D12Resource** texture,
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>& decodedData,
    D3D12_SUBRESOURCE_DATA& subresource,
    size_t maxsize = 0);
```

Alternatively you can use [Windows Imaging Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to write your own implementation, especially if you would like to have more control.