# Creating a texture from a image in DX 12 VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directx, managed-directx, direct3d12

I just want know Directx 12 API to create texture from image.

For DX11 it is D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile and for DX9 it is D3DXCreateTextureFromFileEx and for DX12 ?

Comment: The question is same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492720/c-directx-12-how-to-create-a-texture-from-a-bitmap-file

Comment: D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11 are support utilities, not core parts of Direct3D, and in any case are deprecated per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663275.aspx). [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) has a DDS and WIC-based image texture loader for DirectX 11. DirectX 12 support is in progress. That said, why are you using DirectX 12 instead of DirectX 11 for your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things are a little bit better by now. Microsoft rewrote their DDSTextureLoader for DX12 and released it as part of their MiniEngine on GitHub
https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/MiniEngine/Core/DDSTextureLoader.cpp

You also may want to take a look at my derivative work that is intended to make use of the DDSTextureLoader a bit easier outside of MiniEngine.
https://github.com/ClemensX/ShadedPath12/blob/master/ShadedPath12/ShadedPath12/DDSTextureLoader.cpp

I use this loader for all my texture files. It parses DDS (DirectDrawSurface) file format pretty well, including mipmaps.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one.

Direct3D 12 is a low-level API. A *very* low-level API. It doesn't have convenience functions that create textures out of whole cloth from just a filename. If you want to create a texture, you have to work for it. You have to load the file, figure out what format you want it in, allocate memory for it by asking the system how much memory it would take, then go through a complex series of steps to transfer your loaded image into that memory.

Answer (score 1):

The official 'utility header' for Direct3D 12 is [d3dx12.h](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/blob/master/Templates/DirectX12App/Common/d3dx12.h). It's an inline header and has no DLL or static library, so the functionality provided is limited to true helpers. It has no equivalent to `D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile`. It is not included as part of the Windows SDK, but instead is provided under the MIT license and you are expected to just copy it into your project--it's included in the various DirectX 12 Visual Studio templates including my [Direct3D Game templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/wiki).

You can use the `DDSTextureLoader` and `WICTextureLoader` modules provided in the [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12) for some ready-to-use texture loader for Direct3D 12. See [this tutorial lesson](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Sprites-and-textures).

> It's worth noting that D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11 are all deprecated and only available as part of the legacy DirectX SDK per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). In other words, you shouldn't be using `D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile` for your Direct3D 11 code. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/) for a full list of D3DX9/10/11 replacements. *TL;DR:* use `DDSTextureLoader` and `WICTextureLoader` in [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 11](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK11).

Answer (score 0):

Google keeps referring to this topic for questions around DX-12 and textures, so let's update.

**1. Managed**

If you insist on "managed" check out the samples with the last version of SharpDX (2019)

https://github.com/discosultan/dx12-game-programming

It provides a C# interface to DX-12 native and it works, there are a lot of very nice  samples, including texturing,

- 09-Crate loads a single DDS texture and shows it on a cube
- 09-TexColumns shows basic UV-coordinate actions on various shapes

.. but IMHO it's not really advisable, to keep depending on the *good old* SharpDX library, because that library is [not maintained anymore](http://sharpdx.org/). I can't advise good alternatives for C# atm, I'm not an expert on Unity and Vulkan.

**2. Unmanaged**

As mentioned earlier in this topic, DX-12 things improve. They still do. Check out Chuck Walbourn's current samples here,

https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples

For straight PC/x64, you'll find this,

https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/PCSamples

For PC/UWP, you'll find this,

https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/UWPSamples

These are very nice x64 unmanaged C++ 14.0 examples, using DirectXtk for DirectX-12. Last update in the Master was 3 months ago. Examples involving textures, also straight bitmap textures are

- SimpleTexturePC12 loads a single .jpg texture and shows it in front view
- DirectXTKSimpleSample12 loads several textures
- Graphics\VideoTexturePC12 shows a dynamic texture read from an .mp4 video

These projects are configured for VS2017, but they convert out of the box when loading them in VS2019 and they compile and run ok.

**Other sources**

A known switchboard on DX-12 is [vinjn on github](https://github.com/vinjn/awesome-d3d12), his page is

http://www.vinjn.com/awesome-d3d12/

Navigate from there to study articles and find various other samples.

There is a 3dgep.com tutorial on the subject of DX12 textures, that is

https://www.3dgep.com/learning-directx-12-4/

.. accompanied by

https://github.com/jpvanoosten/LearningDirectX12